# How can I tell maven plugin that my JSPs live in `/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp` and not `src/main/scripts`?

Tags: java, maven, jsp, war

I have a Java / Spring MVC project that's built with Maven (using Eclipse/STS).

Everything works great and my JSP files live in this folder ...

`.../myproject/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp`

I'm trying to use [The Apache Sling JSPC Maven Plugin](https://sling.apache.org/components/jspc-maven-plugin/) to compile the JSPs into classes, and deliver them in the WAR's /classes folder.

When I run the maven build with the plugin in place, I get this error ...

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: basedir .../myproject/src/main/scripts does not exist`

I appears the plugin expects my JSPs to live in `/src/main/scripts`.

How can I tell maven and the plugin that my JSPs live in `/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp` and not `src/main/scripts` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `<sourceDirectory>` as per the documentation https://sling.apache.org/components/jspc-maven-plugin/jspc-mojo.html

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try and report back.

Comment: I gave the source directory but it still complains